# How to wrap any content or element outside table tr tag with tr or td tags properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have template content with table that was not wrapped properly inside `tr` or `td` tag.

```
var tamplate = `
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Name of Location</td>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td>Gender</td>
                    </tr>

                {% for row in Data %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{row.LocationID}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.LocationName}}</td>
                        {% if row.Foreign==True %}
                        <td>I love my country</td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td>I wish to visit {{row.LocationName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
`; // receive content of template
```

Therefore, I would like to wrap any text or element that are not inside `tr` tag with `tr` or `td` according to their hierarchy order and hide them. This would look like this:

```
<table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Name of Location</td>
                            <td>Last Name</td>
                            <td>Gender</td>
                        </tr>

                    <tr style="display:none;"><td>{% for row in Data %}</td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{row.LocationID}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.LocationName}}</td>
                            <td style="display:none;">{% if row.Foreign==True %}</td>
                            <td>I love my country</td>
                            <td style="display:none;">{% else %}</td>
                            <td>I wish to visit {{row.LocationName}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr style="display:none;"><td>{% endid %}</td></tr>
                    <tr style="display:none;"><td>{% endfor %}</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I have no clue how to check if element or content is not inside `tr` or `td` of table tag and to wrap them accordingly.

Any suggestion or idea is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Group `tr` elements with `tbody` tag and the other elements outside `tr` you can use `tr` or `td` tags

The only way to group table rows in a wrapper element is **using the `tbody`** tag. Any other element, you are going to break your HTML validation.

You can group the other elements outside `tr` elements inside `tr` elements and wrap all together inside `tbody` tag.

In this case your code will be similar to this:

```
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    .
                    .
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    .
                    .
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

As you noticed, we can use more than one `tbody` tag inside a table. Use this to wrap your `tr` elements.